# Remove facets from ggplot and instead display on a single chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a plot that is very similar to one that I made for a stakeholder:

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  summarise(av_price = mean(price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color)) +
  geom_bar(aes(weight = av_price)) +
  facet_wrap(cut ~ .)
```

Looks like:
[image]

I've been asked to remove the facets and instead display each cut on the same chart but with some space between each (and perhaps each with their own color for readability?)

I do not know how to get this done. Tried:

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  summarise(av_price = mean(price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color, cut)) +
  geom_bar(aes(weight = av_price))
```

> Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.

How can I display each cut on a single chart as opposed to facets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution:

```
diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  summarise(av_price = mean(price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(color, av_price, fill=cut)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~cut, nrow=1) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]